# Modifying known probability density function using another pdf as an initial condition

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

My question is for a brownian motion type process with two physically different regions. Region 1 is between points A and B and region 2 is between points B and C. The time taken to travel between two points A and B is a stochastic quantity $T_1$. Say I know that the time taken to travel between A and B follows a gaussian distribution i.e.

$$P(T_1) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp\bigg[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{(T_1 - \langle T_1\rangle)^2}{\sigma^2} \bigg]$$

where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the distribution as expected. And that I know once you enter region 2 the time to travel between the points B and C is another stochastic quantity $T_2$ with its own pdf $G(T_2)$ that is generically not gaussian. As an example

$$G(T_2) = \alpha \cdot T_2 \cdot e^{-\beta\cdot T_2^2}$$

but in practice it could be any kind of pdf.

My question is how can you combine the knowledge of the pdf for $T_1$ and seperately the pdf for $T_2$ to work out the pdf for the time taken to travel the total distance from A to B and then to C, $T_3$. Intuitively given that $P(T_1)$ is a simple gaussian distribution. I would expect the full pdf to just be a more spread out version of $G(T_2)$ but I am not sure how to show this explicitly or quantify it.

Any help to how I can combine pdfs in this way (even if it has to be numerically) would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to math.stackexchange!

This looks like a convolution problem. You can look up what convolutions are and how they are used (here's [one](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Convolution/Convolution2.html) resource), but it's also useful to show how one can obtain the main convolution formula from simple arguments since such arguments are not often shown.

Let $P(t_1)$ be the probability density for moving from $A$ to $B$ in time $t_1$ and $G(t_2)$ be the probability density for moving from $B$ to $C$ in time $t_2$. Then, let's denote the probability density for moving from $A$ to $B$ to $C$ as $H(t_\text{tot})$. Noting that $t_{\text{tot}} = t_1 + t_2$ by constraint, we can find the probability density for $H$ by integrating our distributions of $P(t_1)$ and $G(t_2)$ over their domains subject to that constraint. We then have

\begin{align}
H(t_\text{tot}) &= \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dt_1 \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dt_2\, \delta(t_\text{tot}- t_1 - t_2) P(t_1) G(t_2)\\[.5em]
& = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dt_1\, P(t_1) G(t_{\text{tot}}-t_1)
\end{align}

which is the standard formula for convolutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition).

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I'm looking for! When trying to Google the answer I kept stumbling on convolution stuff which I couldn't understand but the way you've presented it makes sense so thanks 